# Vercel build size vs local build size is different

Tags: nuxt.js, web-deployment, limit, serverless, vercel

I'm using Vercel to deploy my Nuxt project (via gitlab) and recently my build fails with error message

> "The serverless function "index" is 119.68 mb which exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb."

It's kinda strange because when I tried to build it locally my `dist` folder is only about 7.92MB. Does anyone have the same problem? How do you trace the size of your Nuxt project in a Vercel build? What causing the local build to be different than the one pushed to Vercel?

I've tried to build it locally and turns out it only 7.92 MB, isn't the build should be the same to the one pushed to Vercel?

Here is my `nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'maimbau',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Server Configuration
  server: {     
    port: 8000, // default: 3000     
    host: 'localhost', // default: localhost   
  },   // other configs 

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: '@/plugins/vue-awesome-swiper', mode: 'client' },
    { src: "@/plugins/aos", ssr: false }
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/stylelint
    '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],

  tailwindcss: {
    configPath: 'tailwind.config.js',
    exposeConfig: false,
    config: {},
    injectPosition: 0,
  },

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {},

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
        "postcss-custom-properties": false
      },
    },
  },
  buildDir: 'dist',
  router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      routes.push({
        name: 'demo_recipient',
        path: '/demo/undangan/:theme/:greeting/:recipient',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/demo/undangan/_theme.vue')
      }),
      routes.push({
        name: 'webview_recipient',
        path: '/:catin/:greeting/:recipient',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/_catin/index.vue')
      })
    }
  }
}
```

And my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "maimbau",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 8000",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "dev:local": "nuxt",
    "analyze": "nuxt build --analyze",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:style": "stylelint \"**/*.{vue,css}\" --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js && npm run lint:style"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "firebase": "^9.8.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "swiper": "^5.4.5",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^5.0.2",
    "vue-tailwind-modal": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.14.7",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^6.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module": "^4.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.12.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^22.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, mind sharing your Nuxt configuration + package.json (+ anything that you judge relevant)?

Comment: sure, here is my nuxt.config.js https://pastecode.io/s/6w8o7jb2 and here is my package.json https://pastecode.io/s/767ecrhu
as for the vercel build/settings I'm using default setting

Comment: This is a Nuxt2 app, the default for such are `ssr: true` and `target: 'server'`. Hence, Vercel is trying to build your app and ship it as a serverless Edge function (I suppose). Is it something that you're actually trying to achieve? Or did you meant to ship it as SSG (`target: 'static'`)?

Comment: oh yeah I just find that when I looked into the vercel build log https://pastecode.io/s/8z8uejwo I found the command that install the devDependencies (in line 15), I have tried overriding the build command in vercel from default to 'npm run build' just like I did in local machine but it has no effect

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to deploy my nuxt app into serverless function because in the future I plan to use SEO for my app

Comment: I'm not sure that you can deploy a Nuxt2 app as an Edge function on Vercel. Totally feasible with Nuxt3 tho. Meanwhile, if you want to have SEO, SSG is totally fine too. Edge rendering is actually something different, that brings SEO benefits too but it's not why you choose it usually. Also, it will require some restrictions in terms of size (which Nuxt2 is not good at).

Comment: so, the option is upgrade to nuxt3 or switch to SSG? my project required for web crawler to get the head tag (sharing link via whatsapp/ig/fb/etc) is it still possible with SSG?

Comment: also, my nuxt project involves dyamic routes like this: myweb.app/dynamic_route where the app get the dynamic_route value and get the value from firebase realtime database to generate a new page

Comment: just now i've tried adding target:'static' in nuxt.config.js and tried to release again, I still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon this issues in github https://github.com/nuxt/vercel-builder/issues/633 I just specify the version of vercel builder in `vercel.json`
from:

```json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "nuxt.config.js",
        "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder"
      }
    ]
  }
```

to:

```json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "nuxt.config.js",
        "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder@0.21.3"
      }
    ]
  }
```

and it works like charm!